# Subtract 2 dates in bash

Tags: bash

I have 2 strings **s1** and **s2** (representing dates) in bash of the form

```
s1="Fri Sep 10 22:24:51 IST 2021"
s2="Fri Sep 10 22:45:55 IST 2021"
```

I want to subtract these dates and get the result in the format **HH:MM:SS**

I have tried the following piece of code (to at least convert the strings to date)

```
d1=$(date -s $s1 +%s)
d2=$(date -s $s2 +%s)
d3=$d2-$d1
echo "$d3"
```

but ended up with the following error

```
date: extra operand ‘10’
```

This is the sample output I desire

```
Subtracted Date in HH:MM:SS is "00:21:04"
```

I am stuck here and don't know how to proceed further. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: This might help: [How to subtract two time stamps along with their dates in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1158870/336375)

Comment: You need to quote the parameter expansions, and use arithmetic expansion to do the actual arithmetic.

Comment: @Cyrus [How to subtract two time stamps along with their dates in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1158870/336375) is not able to track the difference exceeding 24 hours. Any idea on how to proceed in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Convert both timestamps with GNU `date` to seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. Subtract them and convert the result to the desired format.

```
s1="Fri Sep 10 22:24:51 IST 2021"
s2="Fri Sep 10 22:45:55 IST 2021"

diff=$(( $(date -d "$s2" +%s) - $(date -d "$s1" +%s) ))
date -d "@$diff" -u +%H:%M:%S
```

Output:

```
00:21:04
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the difference between both dates is greater than 24 hours. This is correct for the provided specific dates but is not a general method

Comment: For a general method you would have to remove the last line and calculate the hours, minutes and seconds from $diff.